# Is It Possible to Center/Scale An Image Inside A Fluid Width Container With A Fixed Aspect Ratio?

Tags: html, image, css, layout

So it's possible to center and scale an image of unknown dimensions within a variable width and height container [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/MwZpPa):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.Wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Wrapper--landscape {
  float: right;
  background: #DDD;
}

.Wrapper--portrait {
  background: #AAA;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--landscape">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/316978/landscape.jpg">
</div>
  
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--portrait">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/316978/portrait.jpg">
</div>
```

And it's possible to create a fluid width container with a fixed aspect ratio [Codepen(http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/rVoyoL):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper--left {
  float: left;
}

.Wrapper--left {
  float: right;
}

.AspectRatioBox {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.AspectRatioBox--6-4 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 66.666666%;
  background: #CCC;
}

.AspectRatioBox--6-4::after {
  content: '6:4';
}

.AspectRatioBox--16-9 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background: #666;
}

.AspectRatioBox--16-9::after {
  content: '16:9';
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--left">
  <div class="AspectRatioBox AspectRatioBox--6-4"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--right">
  <div class="AspectRatioBox AspectRatioBox--16-9"></div>
</div>
```

But is there any way of doing both at the same time? The problem with combining the two approaches above, is that the method for giving the containers an intrinsic ratio involves using padding to give the container it's visual height. This won't play well with the first technique which involves giving the image `max-height: 100%` as the height of the container will be `0`.

Note: I'm looking for a CSS-only solution that works across modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is yes - by using an extra container to create a new context for the image: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Pedr/pen/dowvLd)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.CenteringContainer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.CenteringContainer:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.Wrapper--landscape {
  float: right;
  background: #DDD;
}

.Wrapper--portrait {
  background: #AAA;
}

.IntrinsicContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.IntrinsicContainer-context {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--landscape">
  
  <div class="IntrinsicContainer">
    <div class="IntrinsicContainer-context CenteringContainer">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/316978/landscape.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="Wrapper Wrapper--portrait">
  <div class="IntrinsicContainer">
    <div class="IntrinsicContainer-context CenteringContainer">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/316978/portrait.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```